# C# - Saving Dataset to XML

Tags: c#, xml

Iam using the WriteXml() of a dataset to save the data I have in the dataset to an XML. When I save the dataset value into the XML file the format of the file is like code below.

I save the dataset like this: `Order_Dataset.WriteXml(@"C:\Orders", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)`

How can I write so that the XMLNS adress dose not shows in my XML file?? XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema should do the work but it wont

`<Order_Dataset xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Order_Dataset.xsd">
  <Order>
    <OrderName>Coffe</OrderName>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <OrderDate>2011-02-20T14:11:21+01:00</OrderDate>
  </Order>`

Comment: Also, you cannot ignore the schema in a normal DataSet, because it is intrinsic to the way DataSets work. On strongly-typed DataSets allow you to ignore the schema, as they are usually stored in an accompanying .xsd.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the namespace of DataSet before saving it?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
ds.Namespace = "";
ds.WriteXml(...);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is better now. I was wondering if its possible to replace the DataSet name aswell, I mean insteas of showing the <Order_Dataset> writing someting else?

Comment: Okej I will try it, thnx again :D

Comment: But the XML only just a dump of your Dataset, Table and Column namings. It might be best to structure the DataSet in a more business oriented way, then export the XML and use XSLT to rename the elements?

Comment: Right know I save the dataset exactly as it is. How can structure the DataSet? Iam goeing to use XSLT later for transforming the XML.

Comment: You can't change the format of the DataSet XML unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

DataSet has internal variable fTopLevelTable that is changed only if a XML file is loaded. Use debugger to see difference after you load your hand changed XML into... This does the trick if you create DataSet by code or with ReadXmlSchema().

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(DataSet).GetField("fTopLevelTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
fieldInfo.SetValue(yourDS, true);
```